# CalledFromWrongThreadException when adding TextView

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have implemeted a custom camera and I want it to go, after a period of time into a standby state. The standby concsists from a stopPreview, a camera release and a view that tells the user to tap in order to exit the standby. Because I set the text within the new thread, I get the CalledFromWrongThreadException, but I don't know what the solution could be. I found other posts around, but none of them really worked.

Code:

```
    private void initCamera()
        {//more code


                threadModifiedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                Thread standbyThread = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            while (timeCounter > 0)
                            {
                                if (!activeThread)
                                {
                                    sleep(100);
                                    if (timeCounter % 10 == 0)
                                    {
                                        threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage((int) timeCounter / 10);
                                    }
                                    timeCounter--;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mCamera.stopPreview();
                        mCamera.release();
                        TextView standbytext = new TextView(SlicesActivity.this);
                        standbytext.setText("Tap to exit standby mode");
                        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(id.FrameLayout_camera_preview);
                        preview.addView(standbytext);

                    }
                };
                standbyThread.start();

//more code}
```

And

```
    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction()
    {
        Log.d("~~~~~~~~~", "apasat");
        activeThread = true;
            timerCounter = 300;


    }

    private Handler threadHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
        {
            // whenever the Thread notifies this handler we have
            // only this behavior
            threadModifiedText.setText("\ncounter is " + Integer.toString(msg.what));
        }
    };
```

Please guys, give me some suggestions. 10x

Comment: you can't set standbytext in your thread..you should do it on your UIThread

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO: update your UI here
        }
    });
```

in your thread to update UI

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set text values inside any thread except the UI thread. Complete your background thread operations and set the text value after your operations are over in the UI thread.